# Submenus of all menus are getting opened by click

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a few menus with submenus, the problem is when I click on menu all submenus got opened. How to open only parent submenus?

[image]

```
  const [subMenu, setSubMenu] = useState(false)
  
  const routes = [
    {
      name: 'Welcome',
      path: '/intro',
      logo: <ArrowRight />,
      items: [
        { item: 'About the course' },
        { item: 'How to use platform' },
        { item: 'Diagnostic test' },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Lesson 1',
      path: '/lesson_1',
      logo: <ArrowRight />,
      items: [
        { item: 'About the course' },
        { item: 'How to use platform' },
        { item: 'Diagnostic test' },
      ],
    },
  ]

return (
            <nav className="flex flex-col border-b pb-7">
              {routes.map((i, index) => {
                return (
                    <div>
                      <div
                        onClick={() => setSubMenu(!subMenu)}
                        className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between mx-2 my-1 transform pl-6
                      transition-transform ease-in duration-200 text-gray-500 hover:bg-slate-100 
                      rounded-lg "
                      >
                        <p className="text-lg">{i.name}</p>
                        <span className="inline-flex items-center h-12 w-8 text-lg">
                          {i.logo}
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        {subMenu && (
                          <div>
                            {i.items.map((i, ind) => {
                              return (
                                <div
                                  key={ind}
                                  className="flex flex-col mx-5 my-1 transform pl-3 py-2 transition-transform
                                   ease-in duration-200 text-gray-500 hover:bg-slate-100 rounded-lg "
                                >
                                  {i.item}
                                </div>
                              )
                            })}
                          </div>
                        )}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                )
              })}
            </nav>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your component has only one `subMenu` Boolean control flag, but many menus.  You either have an array of control flags so each sub-menu receives its own flag, or you create a `MenuItem` component, and then the entire menu is a construction of `MenuItem` instances, and the `MenuItem` component, since it is just one menu, requires just one Boolean.

At this point I should point you to ready-made menu components, as it probably is a saner choice.

For academic purposes, I present you a simple menu in the rest of the answser.

### Creating A Menu Bar

1. Create a menu item component that displays text and a visual cue if the item is meant to show a sub-set of menu items (i. e., has a sub-menu).
2. Create a menu component to control any menu behavior and to serve as the parent of other menu items.
3. Build the menu bar out of menu item and menu components.

#### The Menu Component

This is simple:  Just a div that renders the component's children in it.

```
export type MenuProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

function Menu(props: MenuProps) {
  return <div className="menu">{props.children}</div>;
}

export default Menu;
```

#### The MenuItem Component

This one handles the logic of showing or hiding the sub-menu.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export type MenuItemProps = {
  text: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

function MenuItem({ text, onClick, children }: MenuItemProps) {
  const [subMenu, setSubMenu] = useState(false);
  const classes = `menu-item ${children ? 'has-children' : ''}`;

  function handleClick() {
    if (children) {
      setSubMenu(!subMenu);
    }
    (onClick ?? (() => {}))();
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes} onClick={handleClick}>
        <span>{text}</span>
        {(children && '>') ?? null}
      </div>
      {(subMenu && children) ?? null}
    </>
  );
}

export default MenuItem;
```

As seen in the code, this is the one that defines the Boolean control flag that handles visibility of its children, and just its own children, meaning that other sub-menu children's visibility is not affected.

#### Build the Menu Bar

This you can place somewhere you see fit.  Production-grade code would have a `MenuBar` component that encapsulates this.  The example has this in the `App` component.

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import Menu from './Menu';
import MenuItem from './MenuItem';

import './style.css';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  function handleMenuClick() {
    console.log('A menu was clicked.');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Menu Example</h1>
      <nav>
        <Menu>
          <MenuItem text="Welcome" onClick={handleMenuClick}>
            <Menu>
              <MenuItem text="Welcome 001" onClick={handleMenuClick} />
              <MenuItem text="Welcome 002" onClick={handleMenuClick} />
            </Menu>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem text="Lesson 1" onClick={handleMenuClick}>
            <Menu>
              <MenuItem text="Stuff 101" onClick={handleMenuClick} />
              <MenuItem text="Stuff 201" onClick={handleMenuClick} />
            </Menu>
          </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Finally, I show you the basic styling I did:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div.menu-item {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  min-width: 10em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.menu-item.has-children {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

div.menu {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  border: 0.1em solid rgb(9, 101, 158);
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}
```

That creates this:

[image: Output Example]

You can see this live [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nlamyq?file=src%2FApp.tsx).